# Not getting Operation Count for Operation Queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

```
RemoteImageDownloader *imgView = (RemoteImageDownloader*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    if (imgView == nil)
    {
        imgView = [[RemoteImageDownloader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, cell.frame.size.height)];
        imgView.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    }
    imgView.image = nil;
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    imgView.opQueue = self.opQueue;
    //[imgView performSelector:@selector(DownloadRemoteImageforURL:withCachingOption:) withObject:[_marrImgUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if ([self checkDocDirectoryforFileName:[[_marrImgUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent]])
    {
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[self checkDocDirectoryforFileName:[[_marrImgUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent]]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [imgView DownloadRemoteImageforURL:[_marrImgUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCachingOption:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData isNeedtoSaveinDocumentDirectory:YES];
    }

-(void)DownloadRemoteImageforURL:(NSString*)strURL withCachingOption:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)urlCachePolicy isNeedtoSaveinDocumentDirectory:(BOOL)isNeedSave
{

ImageLoader *subCategoryImgLoader = [[[ImageLoader alloc] initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]] autorelease];

subCategoryImgLoader.target = self;
subCategoryImgLoader.didFinishSelector = @selector(imageDownloadDidFinishwithData:andOperation:);
subCategoryImgLoader.didFailSelector = @selector(imageDownloadfailedwithErrorDesc:andOperation:);
[self.opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];

if ([self.opQueue operationCount] > 0)
{
    NSOperation *lastOperation = [[self.opQueue operations] lastObject];

    [subCategoryImgLoader addDependency:lastOperation];
}

[self.opQueue addOperation:subCategoryImgLoader];

if (_actIndicatorView)
{
    [_actIndicatorView removeFromSuperview], _actIndicatorView = nil;
}

_actIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
_actIndicatorView.tag = 100;
_actIndicatorView.center = self.center;
[self addSubview:_actIndicatorView];
[_actIndicatorView startAnimating];
}
```

In the above code `ImageLoader` is the subclass of `NSOperation`. While I'm checking the operation count, I'm getting zero though I'm adding operations into it. Please let me know if I've done any mistakes. I'm not getting what mistakes I've done so I'm getting zero operation count.

I have created the instance of queue and it is created only once and I'm using the same instance instead of creating again and again. After adding any operation it is showing it has one operation but while I'm going to add another one then I'm getting zero count.

`RemoteImageDownloader` is a subclass of `UIImageView`. I have created that instance in a `UIViewcontroller`.

Hope now it will be easy to understand what I' doing actually.

Now I commented the line `[self.opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];`. Now it is getting the operation count. Can anyone tell me why so?

Comment: Why do you set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 2 if the new operation will always have to wait the previous one? Why don't you just set it to 1?

Comment: Did you actually create the queue instance?

Comment: Are you sure the operations you've added to it haven't all finished by the time you check that?

Comment: Ok, I haven't checked that. I'll check that and will update.

Comment: What is the reason of down vote? Is it a duplicate question? Please let me know the link I'll check the link and correct myself.

Comment: Now I commented the line `[self.opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];`. Now it is getting the operation count. Can anyone tell me why so?

Comment: If you are using `NSURLConnection` inside your operation and haven't created a "Concurrent" operation, then your operation may only be starting the request and not waiting for the response before declaring itself finished.  It will therefore be removed from the queue immediately.  If this is the case then using AFNetworking instead of creating your own operations is a common solution...

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for

> "I am sending message x to property y of my object but it returns 0 and it shouldn't"

is that you haven't set a value for the property. i.e. in your case `self.opQueue` is `nil`.

**Edit**  *We have eliminated the above as the problem.  However, what is below is still relevant*.

Having said that, you also have a race condition since the operation count may change between your test for it being greater than 0 and adding the dependency (e.g. if the operation finishes).

You should probably do something like this:

```
NSOperation* lastOp = [[self.opQueue operations] lastObject];
if (lastOp != nil)
{
    [subCategoryImgLoader addDependency:lastOp];
}
```

The documentation for operationCount contains

> The value returned by this method reflects the instantaneous number of objects in the queue and changes as operations are completed. As a result, by the time you use the returned value, the actual number of operations may be different. **You should therefore use this value only for approximate guidance and should not rely on it for object enumerations or other precise calculations**.

(my bold)

I suspect that what is happening when you set the max operations to 2 is that, by the time you get back to your code for the second time, there really are no operations left on the queue.